# App stuck while trying to authorize health kit

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

i'm trying to get authorization for my app in order to be able to read and write heart rate for a huawei smart band. However, every time i start the app it gets stuck on the login screen as soon as the request for authorization begins...
The app is not being redirected to anywhere to give authorization, its just stuck and im not able to get any kind of response from my app, even the buttons from the login screen are non responsive.

Here's the login code where i'm asking for authorization.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import com.huawei.hms.hihealth.HuaweiHiHealth
import com.huawei.hms.hihealth.SettingController
import com.huawei.hms.hihealth.data.Scopes

class login : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mSettingController: SettingController?  = null
    private val REQUEST_AUTH = 1002
    private val TAG = "HealthKitAuthActivity"
    private var mContext: Context? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //Inicia el pedido de autorizacion por parte del usuario, una sola vez por instalacion
        initService()
        //Proceso de autorizacion
        requestAuth()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val irMain: Button = findViewById(R.id.login)
        irMain.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Menu::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    private fun initService(){
        mContext = this
        Log.i(TAG, "HiHealthKitClient connect to service")
        mSettingController = HuaweiHiHealth.getSettingController(mContext!!)
    }
    private fun requestAuth(){
        val scopes = arrayOf(
            //VER Y GUARDAR EL RITMO CARDIACO DEL USUARIO
            Scopes.HEALTHKIT_HEARTRATE_READ, Scopes.HEALTHKIT_OXYGEN_SATURATION_READ,
            //VER Y GUARDAR LA SATURACION DE OXIGENO DEL USUARIO
            Scopes.HEALTHKIT_HEARTRATE_WRITE, Scopes.HEALTHKIT_OXYGEN_SATURATION_WRITE)
        val intent = mSettingController!!.requestAuthorizationIntent(scopes, true)
        Log.i(TAG, "start authorization activity")
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_AUTH)
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Handle only the authorized responses
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_AUTH) {
            // Obtain the authorization response from the intent.
            val result = mSettingController!!.parseHealthKitAuthResultFromIntent(data)
            if (result == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "authorization fail")
                return
            }
            // Check whether the authorization result is successful.
            if (result.isSuccess) {
                Log.i(TAG, "authorization success")
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "authorization fail, errorCode:" + result.errorCode)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

im also authorization fail, error code 28 and W/HmsHealth_kit HealthKitAuthHub: HMS SignInResult result is fail on the run tab on Android Studio.

currently following the documentation on https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/add-permissions-0000001050069726

UPDATE:
This is the logcat

```
2021-09-26 20:41:05.399 17342-17342/? I/.example.catre: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-09-26 20:41:05.399 17342-17342/? I/.example.catre: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-09-26 20:41:05.399 17342-17342/? I/.example.catre: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-09-26 20:41:05.443 17342-17342/? E/.example.catre: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-09-26 20:41:05.443 17342-17342/? E/.example.catre: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-09-26 20:41:05.443 17342-17342/? E/.example.catre: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-09-26 20:41:05.538 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/.example.catre: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2021-09-26 20:41:05.584 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2021-09-26 20:41:05.607 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/AGConnectProvider: AGConnectInitializeProvider#onCreate
2021-09-26 20:41:05.607 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/AGConnectInstance: AGConnectInstance#initialize
2021-09-26 20:41:05.608 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/ServiceRegistrarParser: getServices
2021-09-26 20:41:05.609 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/ServiceRegistrarParser: services:0
2021-09-26 20:41:05.618 17342-17374/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: enter checkHmsIsSpoof
2021-09-26 20:41:05.620 17342-17375/com.example.catrep E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.catrep
2021-09-26 20:41:05.621 17342-17375/com.example.catrep E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-09-26 20:41:05.622 17342-17375/com.example.catrep E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.catrep
2021-09-26 20:41:05.622 17342-17375/com.example.catrep E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-09-26 20:41:05.623 17342-17375/com.example.catrep E/Perf: Fail to get file list oat
2021-09-26 20:41:05.623 17342-17375/com.example.catrep E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-09-26 20:41:05.658 17342-17374/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_ReadApkFileUtil: verifyMDMSignatureV2 verify successful!
2021-09-26 20:41:05.671 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HealthKitAuthActivity: HiHealthKitClient connect to service
2021-09-26 20:41:05.676 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HealthKitAuthActivity: start authorization activity
2021-09-26 20:41:05.731 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/.example.catre: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-26 20:41:05.732 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/.example.catre: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-26 20:41:05.818 17342-17374/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: check hms state: 2
2021-09-26 20:41:05.822 17342-17374/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Succeed to find HMS apk: com.huawei.hwid version: 30003300
2021-09-26 20:41:05.830 17342-17342/com.example.catrep V/Activity: mLastPackageName-com.example.catrep.login
2021-09-26 20:41:05.902 17342-17376/com.example.catrep I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : b7efb54, I285e059637
    Build Date                       : 10/31/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2021-09-26 20:41:05.903 17342-17376/com.example.catrep I/AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S L 8.0.12 AArch64
2021-09-26 20:41:05.907 17342-17376/com.example.catrep I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2021-09-26 20:41:05.909 17342-17376/com.example.catrep W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:194>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2021-09-26 20:41:05.909 17342-17376/com.example.catrep W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID:218>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2021-09-26 20:41:05.899 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:9683): avc: denied { search } for name="kgsl-3d0" dev="sysfs" ino=30286 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c215,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_kgsl:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-09-26 20:41:05.934 17342-17376/com.example.catrep W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-09-26 20:41:06.108 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3282745
2021-09-26 20:41:06.119 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HmsHealth_kit HealthKitAuthHub: HealthKitAuthHubActivity onCreate
2021-09-26 20:41:06.119 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HmsHealth_kit HealthKitAuthHub: init params success, to enable auth is true
2021-09-26 20:41:06.119 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HmsHealth_kit HealthKitAuthHub: HiHealthKitClient connect to service
2021-09-26 20:41:06.119 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HmsHealth_kit HealthKitAuthHub: on signInHwId click
2021-09-26 20:41:06.133 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HianalyticsExist: In isHianalyticsExist, Failed to find class HiAnalyticsConfig.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.133 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HianalyticsExist: hianalytics exist: false
2021-09-26 20:41:06.135 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Builder->biInitFlag :false
2021-09-26 20:41:06.137 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/NetworkKit_CountryCodeBean: main|null|com.huawei.hms.framework.network.grs.local.model.CountryCodeBean|getVendorCountryCode|39|countryCode by ro.hw.country is: UNKNOWN
2021-09-26 20:41:06.139 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/NetworkKit_CountryCodeBean: main|null|com.huawei.hms.framework.network.grs.local.model.CountryCodeBean|getSimCountryCode|74|countryCode by SimCountryIso is: co
2021-09-26 20:41:06.139 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/NetworkKit_CountryCodeBean: main|null|com.huawei.hms.framework.network.grs.local.model.CountryCodeBean|init|32|get issue_country code from SIM_COUNTRY
2021-09-26 20:41:06.140 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_AnalyticsSwitchHolder: not ChinaROM
2021-09-26 20:41:06.143 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_AnalyticsSwitchHolder: Get OOBE failed
2021-09-26 20:41:06.143 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[ACCOUNT]AccountAuthServiceImpl: silentSignIn
2021-09-26 20:41:06.164 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApi: inner hms is empty,hms pkg name is com.huawei.hwid
2021-09-26 20:41:06.166 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApiManager: sendRequest
2021-09-26 20:41:06.167 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: ====== HMSSDK version: 50300301 ======
2021-09-26 20:41:06.168 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: Enter connect, Connection Status: 1
2021-09-26 20:41:06.169 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: connect minVersion:40004000 packageName:com.huawei.hwid
2021-09-26 20:41:06.172 17342-17342/com.example.catrep V/Activity: mLastPackageName-com.huawei.hms.hihealth.activity.HealthKitAuthHubActivity
2021-09-26 20:41:06.172 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_Util: available exist: true
2021-09-26 20:41:06.175 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_Util: available exist: true
2021-09-26 20:41:06.179 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: current versionCode:30003300, minimum version requirements: 40004000
2021-09-26 20:41:06.181 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_AvailableAdapter: The current version does not meet the minimum version requirements
2021-09-26 20:41:06.182 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: check available result: 2
2021-09-26 20:41:06.183 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: bindCoreService3.0 fail, start resolution now.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.184 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: enter HmsCore resolution
2021-09-26 20:41:06.187 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UIUtil: appProcess.importance is 100
2021-09-26 20:41:06.189 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UIUtil: isForground is true***  isLockedState is false
2021-09-26 20:41:06.192 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UIUtil: appProcess.importance is 100
2021-09-26 20:41:06.193 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UIUtil: isForground is true***  isLockedState is false
2021-09-26 20:41:06.194 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_AvailableAdapter: startResolution
2021-09-26 20:41:06.235 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c22503e
2021-09-26 20:41:06.247 17342-17342/com.example.catrep E/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: An exception occurred while reading: setDisplaySideModecom.huawei.android.view.WindowManagerEx$LayoutParamsEx
2021-09-26 20:41:06.248 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapterMgr: onActivityCreate
2021-09-26 20:41:06.250 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapter: target HMS Core packageName is com.huawei.hwid
2021-09-26 20:41:06.251 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapter: old framework HMSCore upgrade process
2021-09-26 20:41:06.253 17342-17342/com.example.catrep E/HMSSDK_SystemUtils: isSystemApp Exception: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.huawei.appmarket
2021-09-26 20:41:06.254 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateManager: app is: com.huawei.appmarket;status is:NOT_INSTALLED
2021-09-26 20:41:06.256 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateManager: In getAndroidMarketSetting, configuration not found for android channel market setting.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.257 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateManager: typeList is empty, no upgrade solution
2021-09-26 20:41:06.275 17342-17342/com.example.catrep V/Activity: mLastPackageName-com.huawei.hms.activity.BridgeActivity
2021-09-26 20:41:06.287 17342-17342/com.example.catrep E/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: An exception occurred while reading: onApplyWindowInsetscom.huawei.android.view.WindowManagerEx$LayoutParamsEx
2021-09-26 20:41:06.319 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@4a144ee
2021-09-26 20:41:06.331 17342-17342/com.example.catrep E/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: An exception occurred while reading: setDisplaySideModecom.huawei.android.view.WindowManagerEx$LayoutParamsEx
2021-09-26 20:41:06.333 17342-17342/com.example.catrep E/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: In initialize, Failed to create 'IUpdateWizard' instance.Invalid name: 
2021-09-26 20:41:06.334 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: Enter finish.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.358 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapter: onBridgeActivityResult
2021-09-26 20:41:06.359 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: notifyFailed result: 28
2021-09-26 20:41:06.360 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApiManager: onConnectionFailed
2021-09-26 20:41:06.362 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: Enter finish.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.363 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_Util: available exist: true
2021-09-26 20:41:06.365 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[AccountSDK]AccountSignInTaskApiCall: ResponseErrorCode.status:907135003
2021-09-26 20:41:06.367 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[AccountSDK]AccountSignInTaskApiCall: signIn complete, response is null, failed
2021-09-26 20:41:06.370 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[AccountSDK]AccountAuthMemCache: saveDefaultAccountSignInAccount start.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.371 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[AccountSDK]AccountAuthMemCache: saveDefaultAccountSignInAccount start.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.376 17342-17389/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: Enter disconnect, Connection Status: 5
2021-09-26 20:41:06.386 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HmsHealth_kit HealthKitAuthHub: silentSignIn failure on exception
2021-09-26 20:41:06.387 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[ACCOUNT]AccountAuthServiceImpl: getSignInIntent
2021-09-26 20:41:06.388 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[AccountSDK]AccountAuthUtil: getSignInIntent
2021-09-26 20:41:06.401 17342-17342/com.example.catrep V/Activity: mLastPackageName-com.huawei.hms.hihealth.activity.HealthKitAuthHubActivity
2021-09-26 20:41:06.428 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@9bf0d8f
2021-09-26 20:41:06.433 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[ACCOUNTSDK]AccountSignInHubActivity: onCreate
2021-09-26 20:41:06.439 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_[ACCOUNTSDK]AccountSignInHubActivity: checkMinVersion start.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.441 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HmsAccountKitVersionCheckUtil: ====== HMSSDK version: 50300301 ======
2021-09-26 20:41:06.441 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HmsAccountKitVersionCheckUtil: check minVersion:40004000
2021-09-26 20:41:06.445 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: current versionCode:30003300, minimum version requirements: 40004000
2021-09-26 20:41:06.447 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_AvailableAdapter: The current version does not meet the minimum version requirements
2021-09-26 20:41:06.449 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UIUtil: appProcess.importance is 100
2021-09-26 20:41:06.450 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UIUtil: isForground is true***  isLockedState is false
2021-09-26 20:41:06.451 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_AvailableAdapter: startResolution
2021-09-26 20:41:06.472 17342-17342/com.example.catrep V/Activity: mLastPackageName-com.huawei.hms.account.internal.ui.activity.AccountSignInHubActivity
2021-09-26 20:41:06.506 17342-17342/com.example.catrep W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@7f00a08
2021-09-26 20:41:06.520 17342-17342/com.example.catrep E/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: An exception occurred while reading: setDisplaySideModecom.huawei.android.view.WindowManagerEx$LayoutParamsEx
2021-09-26 20:41:06.522 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapterMgr: onActivityCreate
2021-09-26 20:41:06.523 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_BridgeActivity: Enter finish.
2021-09-26 20:41:06.528 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapterMgr: finish one
2021-09-26 20:41:06.544 17342-17342/com.example.catrep V/Activity: mLastPackageName-com.huawei.hms.account.internal.ui.activity.AccountSignInHubActivity
2021-09-26 20:41:06.555 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapter: onBridgeActivityDestroy
2021-09-26 20:41:06.556 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapterMgr: onActivityDestroy
2021-09-26 20:41:06.565 17342-17342/com.example.catrep V/Activity: onStop mLastPackageResume = false com.huawei.hms.activity.BridgeActivity@e5c5269
2021-09-26 20:41:06.576 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapter: onBridgeActivityDestroy
2021-09-26 20:41:06.577 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapterMgr: onActivityDestroy
2021-09-26 20:41:06.578 17342-17342/com.example.catrep I/HMSSDK_UpdateAdapterMgr: reset
```

Comment: logcat is very important. if you be able to post logcat from start session to stop, helps to originate the problem. I mean, isn't there any warning related to `too many works on main UI` or any system error?!

Comment: hi@Juancarlord, may i ask does your log contain the error code in [this link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/hihealthstatuscodes-0000001050089560#section10673269124)?

Comment: Is there a more detail log?

Comment: @shirley the logcat was published as requested, would love some insights on it

Comment: @Anna logcat published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following log

> com.huawei.appmarket;status is:NOT_INSTALLED

The upgrade failure may be triggered because the Huawei AppGallery is not installed.
Therefore, please check whether the test device is a Huawei device and whether the Huawei AppGallery is installed.

The possible cause of the login failure is that the health kit depends on the Huawei AppGallery login. If there is no Huawei AppGallery in the test device, an error will be reported.